# nested list comprehension in elixir

Tags: elixir

In order to learn Elixir I would like to resolve this problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=96

In order to go through the board I would start like that:
In python:

```
row_indexes = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"];
col_indexes = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
row_box_indexes = [["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"],["G","H","I"]];
col_box_indexes = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]];

cols = [[r+c for r in row_indexes] for c in col_indexes]
rows = [[r+c for c in col_indexes] for r in row_indexes]
boxes = [[r+c for c in C for r in R] for C in col_box_indexes for R in row_box_indexes]

print(cols) // [['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'F1', 'G1', 'H1', 'I1'],...,['A9', 'B9', 'C9', 'D9', 'E9', 'F9', 'G9', 'H9', 'I9']]
```

I'm struggling using list comprehension in elixir I tried this but it puts me one list with all my result

```
row_indexes = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"];
col_indexes = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
row_box_indexes = [["A","B","C"],["D","E","F"],["G","H","I"]];
col_box_indexes = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]];

# in iex
for c <- col_indexes,
    x <- (for r <- row_indexes, do: r<>c),
    do: x

# ["A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1", "F1", "G1", "H1", "I1", "A2", "B2", "C2", "D2",..., "I5", "A6", "B6", "C6", "D6", "E6", ...]
```

1) is it a good the good way to resolve this problem in Elixir ?

2) could you explain me how I can reach the same result as print(cols) in python ?

Thank you :)

Comment: there is completely different approach possible in elixir.  In brief you spawn a new process for each square on the board, for each row and each column. Then you start passing messages between these processes to evolve the state of the board.  I can explain better in an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Lauro for your answer!
So yes both comprehension are different and it's not possible to do the same thing in python and in Elixir
This solution (probably not the best...) is longer than the python one but it works:

```
  @doc """
  generate all the rows coordinates
      [[{0,0},{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{6,0},{7,0},{8,0},],...]
  """
  def create_rows(size \\ 9) do
    Enum.reduce(0..size - 1, [], fn(ord,acc) ->
      col = Enum.reduce(0..size - 1, [], fn(abs, accu) ->
        [{abs,ord}|accu]
      end)
      |> Enum.reverse
      [col | acc]
    end)
    |> Enum.reverse
  end
```

It will generate this:

```
[
  [{0,0},{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0},{6,0},{7,0},{8,0},],
  [{0,1},{1,1},{2,1},{3,1},{4,1},{5,1},{6,1},{7,1},{8,1},],
  [{0,2},{1,2},{2,2},{3,2},{4,2},{5,2},{6,2},{7,2},{8,2},],
  [{0,3},{1,3},{2,3},{3,3},{4,3},{5,3},{6,3},{7,3},{8,3},],
  [{0,4},{1,4},{2,4},{3,4},{4,4},{5,4},{6,4},{7,4},{8,4},],
  [{0,5},{1,5},{2,5},{3,5},{4,5},{5,5},{6,5},{7,5},{8,5},],
  [{0,6},{1,6},{2,6},{3,6},{4,6},{5,6},{6,6},{7,6},{8,6},],
  [{0,7},{1,7},{2,7},{3,7},{4,7},{5,7},{6,7},{7,7},{8,7},],
  [{0,8},{1,8},{2,8},{3,8},{4,8},{5,8},{6,8},{7,8},{8,8},],
]
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference between both comprehensions. While in python you generate a list on the outer comprehension with the inner one, in the Elixir version there's no nested comprehension to create the nested lists.

The result of `for r <- row_indexes, do: r<>c` in the header will be a list, of course, but it will be iterated over along the results of each `c` to create the *cartesian product of the values of c and r.*

So, each iteration of the comprehension will give you the values of the current `col_index` and the correspondent `r<>c`. And as you are returning just the second key of the comprehension index, you get a single list.

One fix would be doing an actually nested comprehension for the row indexes, like this:

```
for c <- col_indexes do
  for r <- row_indexes do
    r<>c
  end
end
```